# How to validate my input field based on formula

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to validate my input field in a redux form based on a formula.

There are 4 terms in my formula. I would like to restrict the user to type/enter only these 4 terms and make a formula.

TERM1, TERM2, TERM3, TERM4

User can write something in the formula including these 4 terms
TERM1*5,
TERM2/0.2 etc

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following.

```
handleValidate = (text) => {
  const re =    /(TERM\[1-4])/
    return re.test(text)

}
```

The above function will return true if the text sent to it matches the pattern you specified